# javascript scope issue through facebook async api call

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, scope, code-organization

So I am currently working with the facebook javascript sdk. I seem to be out of scope every time I make an api call, and could really use some help here....

```
function ExampleClass(nameValue) {

    //private properties
    var name;
    //etc.

    //public class methods
    this.setName = function() {

        var callback = (function(name) {

            return function(response) {

                name = response.last_name;

                console.log("this is the name " + name);

            }
        })(name);

        FB.api('/me', {
            fields: 'last_name'
        }, callback);

        //check if name has been set - it is still the name handed to the constructor
        console.log(name);

    };

    this.getName = function() {

        return name;

    };



}

var demo = new ExampleClass("initial value");

demo.setName();

console.log(demo.getName());

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I followed along with another question on scope here which I thought seemed to be my problem, but the return the function within the callback did nothing for me. I am at a complete lose here would appreciate any insight you could offer.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What specific error(s) do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors. The name value is just never set using the setName() method. It always remains the initial value of the constructor of that instance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  A callback within an IIFE that returns a function is a complicated construction.  Please back up and describe what you are actually trying to accomplish with the `setName()` method it seems unlikely something this messy is needed.  it is also generally a bad idea to redefine local variables with arguments of the same name as that only confuses a reader of the code as to what you meant and locks you out of accesses the local variable in the higher scope.

Comment: Well this is just a stripped down version so you don't have to read all the unnecessary code. I am trying to create a bunch of classes that will have getters and setters so that I can keep my code more organized and not have fb api calls all over my code. Therefore, I am trying create object with the data handed to it from the facebook api calls so I can deal with my own api as opposed to facebooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do with `.getName()` is get the name into the private variable `name`, then I think you can just do this:

```
function ExampleClass(nameValue) {

    //private properties
    var name;
    //etc.

    //public class methods
    this.setName = function() {

        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
            name = response.last_name;

            //check if name has been set - it is still the name handed to the constructor
            console.log(name);
        });
    };

    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };
}
```

Issues in your previous implementation:

1. You were redefining `name` which hid access to your private property by the same name so it couldn't be used in some contexts.
2. You massively overcomplicated the api callback with an IIFE returning a function.  A simple callback is all that is needed here.
3. You were checking the value of `name` outside of the callback so that check wasn't waiting for the actual new value to be set.  FB callbacks are asynchronous.  That means they happen at some indeterminate time in the future and your other code has already run.  If you want to use the result of a callback, you have to use it IN the actual callback or in a function that you call from the callback.

Issues still present:

1. You're providing no means of notification for when `setName()` is actually done.
2. You've covered up any chance at error handling outside of `ExampleClass` (e.g. it just ignores errors and doesn't propagate anything outside).

---

If you wanted to know when setName was actually  done, the usual way to do that in Javascript is to offer an (optional) callback that can be used:

```
function ExampleClass(nameValue) {

    //private properties
    var name;
    //etc.

    //public class methods
    this.retrieveName = function(callback) {

        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
            name = response.last_name;

            //check if name has been set - it is still the name handed to the constructor
            console.log(name);

            if (callback) {
                // Fixme: also should probably communicate FB API errors here
                callback(name);
            }
        });
    };

    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };
}


var x = new ExampleClass("ted");
x.retrieveName(function(name) {
    // verify both of these are the same now
    console.log(name);
    console.log(x.getName());
});
```

Comment: Well the implementation you have is what I started with, but then I read through some question on here and changed to what I just had. Now, the problem I am still facing here is that when I call getName() below after the object has been instantiate and setName() has also been called it is still the initial value, and not the one assigned to the name by setName()

Comment: @user3832583 - you don't seem to understand Asynchronous operations.  An Async operations completes some time in the future.  You can't just call `setName()` and immediately check the name.  it isn't done yet.  The FB api call has not completed yet.  You cannot try to cover up an async API and use it like a synchronous API.  That just doesn't work (which is what you appear to be trying to do).

Comment: @user3832583 - see the second code example I added with a callback to notify you when the `retriveName()` operation is actually done.